# Running iOS 3.x app on iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios4

I had developed an app with base SDK version to iOS 3.2.3 and deployment target as iOS 3.0 .
However, when I have updated my app now, and tried the ad-hoc build to install it on iOS 4 device, it is failing.
Please suggest if I have to make another build with latest base SDK version or I can stick to my current build?

Comment: You should *always* build against the current SDK, i.e. 4.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always build against the latest SDK version and set the Deployment Target according to your needs.

Comment: But there are some incompatibilities like iOS4 doesnt allow NSXMLParser to be used as a delegate.also I am using description on keyboard for hiding it when using UITextview,iOS4 returns different description and it wont work in my case.Is it still possible to run 3.1.3 base SDK build to run on iOS 4? because the old build in app store works with iOS 4 devices too.

Comment: @amavi: If you have trouble after upgrading to the latest SDK, I am afraid that you have to bite the bullet and update your code. Supporting obsolete SDK versions is a dirty work. Are you 100% sure it makes sense in your case? I don’t think you can still build using 3.x SDK, Apple actively works against this to keep developers and users udpating.

Comment: no no,actually I just wanted to avoid that if it would have installed directly..because the app store version is still supported.But it seems I Will have to do as you suggested.

Comment: I think the Apple policy is to keep apps built on older SDK versions working, but disallow building against old SDKs. This way the users benefit from backward compatibility and developers are prevented from clutching obsolete SDKs.

Comment: haha nice.Yeh I will upgrade my app sure! no other option now.